# is any easier way to build a single web page like react in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

New to Flutter,

I know below question can archive similar goal, but is any other easy way to do so?

[how flutter work with single page web and different route url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561884/how-flutter-work-with-single-page-web-and-different-route-url)

here is react example:

```html
 <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sure there is.

The point is that you would have to use an [external package](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_url_handler).

It's simple to use and you can pass **state from URL and vice versa**.

You would have to implement 2 methods, one for the URL to state and the other for the opposite.

```
SimpleUrlHandler(
    urlToAppState: (BuildContext context, RouteInformation routeInformation) {
        // This is called when a user enters a url or presses the forward/backward
        // button. You should update your app state according to the RouteInformation.
    },
    appStateToUrl: () {
        // This is called when the url should be updated
        // You must return a RouteInformation
    },
    child: YourAppWidget(),
);
```